# Converting mysql procedure to pl-sql procedure

Tags: mysql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to convert my MySQL project to PL/SQL to implement as a apex application. I have a problem about converting stored procedure. It was working when I am using it in MySQL, but it gives error in PL/SQL. I have read about PL/SQL syntax, I think that I have done the necessary changes to convert my stored procedure to PL/SQL format. [image: Here is my error when try to create my procedure]

My code is like following:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE findSuitableRoom
(
   varBuilding_id IN NUMBER,
   varLecture_block_id IN NUMBER,
   varWeek_of_the_day IN NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN 
   SELECT A.room_id
   FROM 
   (
    SELECT room_id, room_number, r.building_id FROM building INNER JOIN
      (SELECT room.room_id, room_number, ruilding_id FROM room INNER JOIN room_building_location 
      ON room.room_id=room_building_location.room_id) AS R 
    ON building.building_id=r.building_id WHERE r.building_id=varBuilding_id 
   ) AS A
   LEFT JOIN
   (
   SELECT room_id FROM timetable WHERE timetable.lecture_block_id=varLecture_block_id AND timetable.week_of_the_day=varWeek_of_the_day
   ) AS B 
   ON A.room_id=B.room_id WHERE B.room_id IS NULL;
END;
```

Comment: A stored procedure in PL/SQL cannot simply execute a SQL statement.  You could modify the stored procedure so that it had an `OUT` parameter that was of type `sys_refcursor` and open that cursor in the procedure.  If you are on 12.1, there is some syntactic sugar for that.  You might be better off using a pipelined table function or a view rather than a procedure, however.

Comment: Can you give a bit more background on how you intend to use the procedure?  If you are just using this to provide data for an APEX screen/ report, my guess is that you want to create a view, add the columns that you need to filter on, and write queries against the view with appropriate `where` clauses.

Comment: Of course, I am trying to prepare room organization application for our university. With this procedure, my purpose is that the lecturer enters the building_id, day and hour that he want to reserve for his lecture. Then the procedure has to display all suitable room ids. That's why I need to take parameters. Actually I do not know can I do this with view?

Answer (score 0):

I think Apex being an Oracle product you should be able to convert your MySQL procedure to a PL/SQL one and use it in your Apex code. You would need to return a REF CURSOR as shown in the converted example below. Here is a [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2144116?tstart=0) to a post on the Oracle community website which has additional example code that is Apex related. You need to scroll down to where the page has `http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=34598:1` and you will see the code below it

You should be able to use the example code from there and the converted procedure below to accomplish your conversion.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE sample_ref_cursor_pkg AS 
  TYPE sample_ref_cursor IS REF CURSOR;
END Types; 
/
create or replace PROCEDURE findSuitableRoom
(
   varBuilding_id IN NUMBER,
   varLecture_block_id IN NUMBER,
   varWeek_of_the_day IN NUMBER
  ,out_cursor OUT sample_ref_cursor_pkg.sample_ref_cursor
) AS
BEGIN 
     OPEN out_cursor 
      FOR
   SELECT A.room_id
   FROM 
   (
    SELECT room_id, room_number, r.building_id FROM building INNER JOIN
      (SELECT room.room_id, room_number, ruilding_id FROM room INNER JOIN     room_building_location 
      ON room.room_id=room_building_location.room_id) AS R 
    ON building.building_id=r.building_id WHERE r.building_id=varBuilding_id 
   ) AS A
   LEFT JOIN
   (
   SELECT room_id FROM timetable WHERE     timetable.lecture_block_id=varLecture_block_id AND     timetable.week_of_the_day=varWeek_of_the_day
   ) AS B 
   ON A.room_id=B.room_id WHERE B.room_id IS NULL;
END;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is no need to create a package just to define a weak ref cursor type.  Just declare the parameter as a `sys_refcursor`.  Unless you need backwards compatibility with really, really old versions of Oracle.

Comment: I am getting error from ` OPEN out_cursor` part, I think I still have syntax problem.